# ${username.value} not giving rendering result, why?

Tags: reactjs, literals

I have this ${username.value} not giving the real value on webpage. do you know why?

```
<script type="text/babel" >
        //build a component
        class Login extends React.Component{
            handleSubmit = (event)=>{
                event.preventDefault()
                const {username, password} = this
                console.log('wht is username.value', username.value)
                alert("Username you input is: ${username.value}, your password is:${password.value}")
            }
            
            render(){
                return(
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        USERNAME: <input ref={c => this.username = c} type="text" name="username"/>&nbsp;
                        PASSWORD: <input ref={c => this.password = c} type="password" name="password"/>&nbsp;
                        <button>login</button>
                    </form>
                )

            }
        }
```

[image: It looks like this, instead of giving me a real value]

Comment: Use backticks for template literals.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `" Variable "`. The following code is correct:

`` alert(`Username you input is: ${username.value}, your password is:${password.value}`) ``

You can read about it: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks, how is your line of code differ from mine? could not see it?

Comment: I get it, `` backtick is needed in this case, rather than 'single quotation mark'